# What's a good pattern for invoking event handler props in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Let's assume a component:

```js
const Foo = ({id, onError}) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        subscribe(id).catch(error => onError(error));
        return () => cleanup(id);
    }, [id, onError]);

  return <div>...</div>;
}
```

The idea is simple-- run an effect that subscribes using the current "id". If the subscription fails, invoke an event handler `onError` that is passed down as a prop.

However, for this to work correctly, the `onError` prop that's passed down must be referentially stable. In other words, if a consumer of my component tried the following, they may run into problems where the effect is run for each render:

```
const Parent = () => {
   // handleError is recreated for each render, causing the effect to run each time
   const handleError = error => {
     console.log("error", error);
   }

   return <Foo id="test" onError={handleError} />
}
```

Instead, they would need to do something like:

```
const Parent = () => {
   // handleError identity is stable
   const handleError = useCallback(error => {
     console.log("error", error);
   },[]);

   return <Foo id="test" onError={handleError} />
}
```

This *works*, but I'm somehow unhappy with it. The consumers of `Foo` need to realize that `onError` must be stable, which is not something that's plainly obvious unless you look at its underlying implementation. It breaks the component encapsulation and consumers can easily run into problems without realizing it.

Is there a better pattern to manage props like event handlers that may be invoked within `useEffect`?

Comment: Are you sure that an `onError` event handler on the component is the right place to handle errors from `subscribe`. I would try to have subscribe handle its own errors. What kind of errors do you expect to handle in this case?

Comment: @HåkenLid Assuming `Foo` is a reusable component, each consumer may handle the error in a different way. It doesn't have to be `onError` specifically, it can be any event (`onSubscribed`, `onDataReceived`, etc.). I was just trying to give a simple example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `onError` from your dependency list, but still call if it changes. For that you can use a ref, and update it via `useEffect` on each render.

You can also use [optional chaining `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to avoid invoking the function if it's `undefined`.

```
const Foo = ({ id, onError }) => {
  const onErrorRef = useRef(); 
  
  useEffect(() => {
    onErrorRef.current = onError;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    subscribe(id).catch(error => onErrorRef.current?.(error));
    return () => cleanup(id);
  }, [id]);

  return <div>...</div>;
}
```